# AngularJS $http returns html source code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the following code to do a http request.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!--head_end-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="company_profile" ng-app="company_profile" ng-controller="company_profileCtrl">
    <h2>&company_name</h2>
    <p><a href="&company_link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">&company_link_text</a>
    </p>
    <p>{{companyProfile}}</p>
  </div>

  <!-- populate company_profile -->
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('company_profile', []);
    app.controller('company_profileCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("single-site.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.companyProfile = response.data;
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However the code returns the source code of the html document it is in.

the `single-site.php` file exists and returns json data.

Thanks for your help

**Edit** I saw three other questions of people who had this problem, but none of them was correctly resolved.

Comment: you are missing the $http.get('/'), in call. And are you sure about your URL ?  We do map the REST API link in it, not the page name.

Comment: try to do a `console.log(response.data)` 
and probably this can help you [link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_json)

Comment: @Aravid, can you elaborate on the missing $http.get('/')? I don't really understand

Comment: @kimiko88 I already tried that, it is also printing the source code of the page to the console

Comment: You are using incorrect URL. But it's hard to help here - only you know how it should be.

Comment: Have you put something like that in your php file [customer.php](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php) ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I use pretty urls by using htaccess, I just tried to call the page without a pretty url and it worked, strange,,,

Comment: @kimiko88 yes I did, It looks like that: "
{"companyProfile": "This is Facebook"}

Comment: Okay, I understood what @Aravind ment, and he was right, can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: probably you need only `$scope.companyProfile = response.data.companyProfile`  but with angularjs and pretty url, you must be carefully

Comment: @Alexander Fuchs, Done,  now you can mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the $http.get('/'), in call. And are you sure about your URL ? We do map the REST API link in it, not the page name.

Like the below code.

```js
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the url field you just have to write the full path. For example https://sitename/index.php/RandomController/yourfunction/
For me it worked!
P.S. I use codeigniter